# How to compare time ranges?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Hi i am trying to compare time ranges,My requirement is when i select time from time-picker dialog it should be under given time ranges for this i wrote below code this is working when i not select 12 or 00 from time picker dialog

**start time:06:00**
**end time:23:00**
**selected time from time picker dialog:12:23**

above timing not suitable for below code can some one help me please

```
     String pattern = "hh:mm";                                            
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
     Date date1 = sdf.parse(startTime);
     Date date2 = sdf.parse(endTime);
     Date date3 = sdf.parse(selectedTime);
     if (((date3.after(date1) || date3.equals(date1)) && (date3.before(date2) || date3.equals(date2)))) {         


     }
     else {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Pickup time should be open and close timings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                         
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code below .

```
 String pattern = "HH:mm";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(startTime);
        Date date2 = sdf.parse(endTime);
        Date date3 = sdf.parse(selectedTime);
        if (date3.compareTo(date1) >= 0 && date3.compareTo(date2) <= 0) {
            // Do your stuff
        } else {
            // Wrong time
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**h** represents Hour in am/pm (1-12)

**H** represents Hour in day (0-23)

Your date is in 24 hour formate so you should use **H** instead of **h**.

Comment: let me try and let you know result

Comment: Use the updated answer . It will cover the equal condition too .

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)**.

> CompareTo method must return negative number if current object is less
>   than other object, positive number if current object is greater than
>   other object and zero if both objects are equal to each other.

**Code Reference**

```
if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0)
{
Log.d("RESULT","date1 older than date2"); 
}
else
{
 Log.d("RESULT","date2 older than date1"); 
}
```

**NOTE**

Make sure your **`TIME format`** is perfect.

Comment: @Krish Glad to hear. Move ahead.